# Doing a DELETE request from <a> tag without constructing forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to force an `<a href>` to do a delete request when clicked instead of a regular `GET`?

The "Rails" way is to dynamically generate a `<form>` tag that adds the appropriate params so that it gets routed to the right place, however I'm not too fond of that much DOM manipulation for such a simple task.

I thought about going the route of something like:

```
$("a.delete").click(function(){
    var do_refresh = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
         url: "my/path/to/delete",
     success: function(){
                  do_refresh = true;
              },
     failure: function(){
                  alert("There is an error");
              }
    });
    return do_refresh; //If this is false, no refresh would happen. If it
                      //is true, it will do a page refresh.
});
```

I'm not sure if the above AJAX stuff will work, as it's just theoretical.  Is there any way to go about this?

**Note:**
Please don't recommend that I use the rails `:method => :delete` on `link_to`, as I'm trying to get away from using the rails helpers in many senses as they pollute your DOM with obtrusive javascript.  I'd like this solution to be put in an external JS file and be included as needed.

Comment: Rails 3 does this with unobtrusive javascript. I don't know all the ins and outs myself, but here's a start: http://www.metaskills.net/2010/1/29/unobtrusive-js-in-rails-3-with-prototype

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

the DELETE method is allowed but not supported on all browsers, so you should take a look here:

[Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Comment: I understand that it is available as AJAX.  I was wondering if there was a NON-AJAX way to do a delete request OTHER than wrapping the request in a dynamic form in the same way the rails helpers do.

Comment: You can set the method to DELETE, but it will only work on Html5, so it will probably cause you some issues with older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i do:

```
$("a.delete").live('click', function() {
        $.post(this.href, "_method=delete", function(data) {
            //do refresh
        });
        return false;
    })
```

But i don't really know which all browsers support it and which don't. I tested it on mac with Firefox 2 and 3.6, safari 3 and chrome beta 5.0.375.70 and it works.

Comment: You set rel=nofollow using jQuery? Just a heads-up: spiders will not run your JS so they're not going to honour that.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks a ton! :) I completely forgot that spiders don't parse the JS. Will use in the markup instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**RESTInTag**](https://github.com/KhaledElAnsari/RESTInTag/) plugin, it will do the ajax requests for you all you have to do is add a couple of extra attributes to your HTML tag

Example:

**HTML**

```
<button class="delete" data-target="my/path/to/delete" data-method="DELETE" data-disabled="true">Delete Article</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".delete").restintag(optionsObj, function() {
    do_refresh = true
},
function() {
    alert("some error happened");
});
```