# Delete Action not working MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Route I have defined is:

```
    map.Route(new Route("Cars/{id}/Delete",  
              new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Car", action = "Delete"}),
              new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

In my view I've got:

```
<a href="/Car/@Model.Id/Delete">Delete</a>
```

Which when run tries to send a request to http://oursite/Car/122/Delete

My delete action in this Car controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    //code is here
}
```

I noticed a couple things:

1. If I run this same code **locally via my PC, the delete works flawlessly** and is able to get to my action method.  I'm running this over IIS 7 / Win 7
2. On our dev server, it's setup obviously via IIS7 but this route fails and says it can't find the route on our route table.  But this is the SAME route table class I am using locally...so why would I get this:

No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

But why would that not work on a dev server?  I see the setup identical in IIS for the most part as far as I can see when I compare my local setup to the server's.

I noticed that also whether localhost or server, if I try and put an [HttpDelete] attribute on my delete action, it doesn't find my action method and I get an error saying it can't find that method.  So not sure why when I take that off, the delete works (localhost only)

Comment: Your URLs don't seem to match.  One says /Discussions and the second one says oursite/Car.  Is it supposed to be /Discussions/Car or /Car/Discussions?

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper to generate your link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Car");
```

The first parameter is your link text, the second is your Action method name, and the third is your Controller name.

See [this MSDN Reference on ActionLink()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070.aspx).

Comment: why do I have to use a helper?  why not just plain <a> regardless if it's not safe, my designers like to create buttons via hyperlinks by decorating them with CSS to make it look like a button.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict You don't *have* to, but it would make this task much easier.  Please post your routes in your question.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Use FireBug to see what exactly the HTTP request is.  There is a disconnect somewhere, you just need to see all the details.

Comment: I have, not seeing anything that sticks out.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share code for the View. How do you build the 'a' tag in the view?

Regarding the [HttpDelete] attribute, it means that the method needs the HTTP 'DELETE' request. The 'a' tag always has a GET request.
[Please refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046448/doing-a-delete-request-from-a-tag-without-constructing-forms)

Comment: The OP did put the `<a />` tag in the original question: `<a href="/Discussions/@Model.Id/Delete">Delete</a>`.

Comment: ok then why is this hyperlink working...it works localhost, just not server without the HttpDelete atttribute

Comment: Yea so GET is fine, it's getting...requesting a delete action by it's href definition

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question. There is no route in the route table that matches your supplied values. You could write that route to do that by writing this in your Global.asax.cs file:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  protected void Application_Start()
  {
    // Specify routes
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route
    {
      Url = "[controller]/[id]/[action]",
      Default = new { controller = "Car" },
      RouterHandler = typeof(MvcRouteHandler)
    });
  }
}
```

Or, you can use existing routes (my personal recommendation) to use the Delete function in your Car controller. To do that, try switching your code to this:

```
<a href="/Car/Delete/@Model.Id">Delete</a>
```

Comment: no I do have a route defined is what I'm saying which again I said this works fine locally over IIS when I run the site.

Answer (score 0):

First name that route

```
map.Route("DeleteCar",new Route("Cars/{id}/Delete",  
          new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Car", action = "Delete"}),
          new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

Then

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("DeleteCar",new{id=Model.Id})">Delete</a>
```

Unless that link goes to a warning screen, I **strongly** suggest that a delete should be a POST or even a DELETE(I think it can be set via ajax)

Answer (score 0):

There's likely a difference in the URL paths between localhost and oursite.  The path "/Car/@Model.Id/Delete" is hard-coded, not resolved and may not work in all environments. As suggested in other answers, use an MVC helper like @Html.ActionLink or @Url.RouteUrl to resolve the path for the local environment.

Comment: the problem with this is we have a UX guy who is painting these links dynamically via JS on the page.  So he's not going to be using MVC helpers but instead plain old hyperlink syntax.  It would be sort of weird to inject helpers if you even can by literal string.

Comment: Is there a way to prove the UX guy with some JS variables, i.e. "DeleteUrl=@Heleroutput;".  This way the UX guy can simply write if(DeleteUrl) navigate;